# Angular ng build does not produce dist folder

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am so frustrated in that I ran ng build but it does not produce dist folder in the project folder. I have no problem with other projects. Strange is that compiler does not give any errors. Could someone please check my project and tell the reason?  https://github.com/vugar005/Report
Kind Regards

Comment: in your `.angular-cli.json`, the output directory is set as: `"outDir": "../MHS",`, change it to `"outDir": "dist",` to generate the `dist` folder.

Comment: Thank you so much faisal. This what I was looking for.

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have seen your repository, and i think the problem is on your `".angular-cli.json"` file. On line 9 you specify `outDir` to `"../MHS"` and it should produce the result into `"../MHS"` folder instead of `"dist"` folder.

As a resolution to your problem, you could change the `outDir` from `"../MHS"` to `"dist"`.

Comment: how is that different from my comment on the question? I'll just give you an upvote for encouragement ;)

Comment: Wow! You saved my life. It worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: Anytime :)
Ouch i don't see that before, really appreciate ;) @Faisal.

Comment: In Angular 7 there is only angular.json. It is now called outputPath.

Answer (score 2):

**This does not apply to this specific case, but it might help others experiencing the same problem.**

In angular.json:

```
projects.<project name>.architect.build.configurations.<configuration>.tsconfig
```

was set to a file that did not exist. Changing this to the correct file fixed the issue in my case.

```json
{
  /* other configuration */
  "projects": {
    /* other configuration */
    "my-library": {
      /* other configuration */
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "project": "projects/my-library/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              /* this used to be a file that did not exist */
              "tsConfig": "projects/my-library/tsconfig.json"
            },
            "development": {
              /* this used to be a file that did not exist */
              "tsConfig": "projects/my-library/tsconfig.json"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looking back at my tsconfig configurations made me realize they were not correct, and I fixed my problem. Thank you!